# Coluna do banco de dados nomeada com alias não encontrada na cláusula WHERE

Tags: sql, query

Tenho essa consulta SQL onde preciso nomear duas vezes uma mesma coluna `datareferencia` para `anobase` e `mesbase`, como segue exemplo. Mas está apresentado erro de coluna não encontrada. Ao meu ver, depois que aplico o alias a coluna passa a existir, mas parece que isso não é verdade.

Minha query:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT CONTAS.contas_id AS contas_id, CONTAS.contastipodetalhe AS contastipodetalhe, CONTAS.contas_nome AS contas_nome, CONTAS.contas_title AS contas_title, CONTAS.contas_datareferencia AS anobase, CONTAS.contas_datareferencia AS mesbase, CONTAS.contas_url AS contas_url, CONTAS.contas_views AS contas_views, CONTAS.contas_downloads AS contas_downloads, CONTAS.contas_date AS contas_date, CONTAS.contas_author AS contas_author, CONTAS.contas_status AS contas_status, CONTASTIPODETALHE.contastipodetalhe_title AS contastipodetalhe_title, CONTASTIPO.contastipo_title AS contastipo_title from (CONTAS join CONTASTIPODETALHE ON CONTAS.contastipodetalhe = CONTASTIPODETALHE.contastipodetalhe_id join CONTASTIPO ON CONTASTIPODETALHE.contastipo = CONTASTIPO.contastipo_id) WHERE contas_status = 1 AND contastipodetalhe = 1 AND year(anobase) = 2016 AND month(mesbase) = 12
```

O erro:

```
Erro ao Ler: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'anobase' in 'where clause'
```

Comment: Não é todo DB que permite o uso de alias nas condições ou ordem. Tentou usando o nome original da coluna?

Comment: não posso utilizar o nome original pois estou renomeando a mesma coluna 2 vezes.

Comment: não consegui ver onde isso impediria o uso do nome original. Aliás, nem vi razão para renomear duas vezes, em vez de usar um nome só. Imagino que tenha alguma, mas não sei qual é.

Comment: eu preciso que tenha dois campos: anobase e mesbase, para que eu possa utilizar a clausula where assim:

WHERE contas_status = 1 AND contastipodetalhe = 1 AND year(anobase) = 2016 AND month(mesbase) = 12

Comment: Para usar assim o nome original resolveria perfeitamente. Mas na resposta do Victor tem mais detalhes de como fazer certo, e com alias.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Essa é a sua consulta original, formatada de uma forma mais legível:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    CONTAS.contas_id AS contas_id,
    CONTAS.contastipodetalhe AS contastipodetalhe,
    CONTAS.contas_nome AS contas_nome,
    CONTAS.contas_title AS contas_title,
    CONTAS.contas_datareferencia AS anobase,
    CONTAS.contas_datareferencia AS mesbase,
    CONTAS.contas_url AS contas_url,
    CONTAS.contas_views AS contas_views,
    CONTAS.contas_downloads AS contas_downloads,
    CONTAS.contas_date AS contas_date,
    CONTAS.contas_author AS contas_author,
    CONTAS.contas_status AS contas_status,
    CONTASTIPODETALHE.contastipodetalhe_title AS contastipodetalhe_title,
    CONTASTIPO.contastipo_title AS contastipo_title
from (
    CONTAS
    join CONTASTIPODETALHE ON CONTAS.contastipodetalhe = CONTASTIPODETALHE.contastipodetalhe_id
    join CONTASTIPO ON CONTASTIPODETALHE.contastipo = CONTASTIPO.contastipo_id
)
WHERE contas_status = 1
AND contastipodetalhe = 1
AND year(anobase) = 2016
AND month(mesbase) = 12
```

Primeiro, esse trecho está errado:

```
CONTAS.contas_datareferencia AS anobase,
CONTAS.contas_datareferencia AS mesbase
```

Isso fará com que ambas as colunas tenham a data inteira, tanto o `anobase` e o `mesbase`, sem separar o ano e o mês. Não importa se eles são separados na cláusula `WHERE`, uma vez que no `SELECT`, não é isso o que você seleciona.

O seu erro é que você está assumindo que primeiro ele escolhe as colunas com o `SELECT` e depois filtra os resultados com o `WHERE`. Mas no SQL, o que ocorre é o contrário. Primeiro ele filtra com o `WHERE` e depois escolhe as colunas e lhes aplica aliases com o `SELECT`. Assim sendo, quando o `WHERE` é processado, o alias ainda não foi visto.

Aqui vai a sua consulta corrigida. Aproveito para colocar aliases nas tabelas e também usá-los dentro da cláusula `WHERE`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    c.contas_id AS contas_id,
    c.contastipodetalhe AS contastipodetalhe,
    c.contas_nome AS contas_nome,
    c.contas_title AS contas_title,
    YEAR(c.contas_datareferencia) AS anobase,
    MONTH(c.contas_datareferencia) AS mesbase,
    c.contas_url AS contas_url,
    c.contas_views AS contas_views,
    c.contas_downloads AS contas_downloads,
    c.contas_date AS contas_date,
    c.contas_author AS contas_author,
    c.contas_status AS contas_status,
    ctd.contastipodetalhe_title AS contastipodetalhe_title,
    ct.contastipo_title AS contastipo_title
FROM Contas c
JOIN ContasTipoDetalhe ctd ON c.contastipodetalhe = ctd.contastipodetalhe_id
JOIN ContasTipo ct ON ctd.contastipo = ct.contastipo_id
WHERE c.contas_status = 1
AND c.contastipodetalhe = 1
AND YEAR(c.contas_datareferencia) = 2016
AND MONTH(c.contas_datareferencia) = 12
```

Nessa consulta, se você preferir, dá até para trocar isso:

```
    YEAR(c.contas_datareferencia) AS anobase,
    MONTH(c.contas_datareferencia) AS mesbase,
```

Por isso:

```
    2016 AS anobase,
    12 AS mesbase,
```

Uma vez que você já sabe de antemão qual é o mês e o ano que você quer.

Se você quiser forçar com que o `SELECT` ocorra antes do `WHERE`, use um parênteses e um sub-`SELECT`, tal como está abaixo. Entretanto, isso não costuma ser uma boa ideia a menos que você saiba muito bem o que está fazendo, pois tende a degradar o desempenho se não for feito com muito cuidado.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        c.contas_id AS contas_id,
        c.contastipodetalhe AS contastipodetalhe,
        c.contas_nome AS contas_nome,
        c.contas_title AS contas_title,
        YEAR(c.contas_datareferencia) AS anobase,
        MONTH(c.contas_datareferencia) AS mesbase,
        c.contas_url AS contas_url,
        c.contas_views AS contas_views,
        c.contas_downloads AS contas_downloads,
        c.contas_date AS contas_date,
        c.contas_author AS contas_author,
        c.contas_status AS contas_status,
        ctd.contastipodetalhe_title AS contastipodetalhe_title,
        ct.contastipo_title AS contastipo_title
    FROM Contas c
    JOIN ContasTipoDetalhe ctd ON c.contastipodetalhe = ctd.contastipodetalhe_id
    JOIN ContasTipo ct ON ctd.contastipo = ct.contastipo_id
) x
WHERE x.contas_status = 1
AND x.contastipodetalhe = 1
AND x.anobase = 2016
AND x.mesbase = 12
```

Comment: perfeito! solução mega correta. Desculpa pelo query sem formatação.
Muito obrigado....
Nem pai faz pra filho o que você fez aqui.... solução de problema de mais de 3 semanas!